# rosmake roboearth failure

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello again...i,ve been trying to compile roboearth for a few days..but i have ecounter an error...can anyone tell me what went wrong?

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package opencyc written to: ]                                                                             [ 2 Active 142/168 Complete ]
[ rosmake ]    /home/azfaryusof/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120423-235030/opencyc/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< opencyc [PASS] [ 0.95 seconds ] -- WARNING: 2 compiler warnings
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> comp_ehow [ make ]
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package comp_ehow written to:c ]                                                                          [ 2 Active 143/168 Complete ]
[ rosmake ]    /home/azfaryusof/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120423-235030/comp_ehow/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< comp_ehow [PASS] [ 54.30 seconds ] -- WARNING: 2 compiler warnings
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> re_ontology [ make ]
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesldb: 212.8 sec ] [ re_ontology: 39.9 sec ]                                                                        [ 2 Active 144/168 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
models/kitchen/tableSetting/.svn/tmp/tempfile.5.tmp
models/kitchen/tableSetting/.svn/tmp/tempfile.6.tmp
models/kitchen/tableSetting/.svn/tmp/tempfile.7.tmp
models/kitchen/tableSetting/.svn/tmp/tempfile.8.tmp
models/kitchen/tableSetting/.svn/entries
models/kitchen/tableSetting/.svn/format
models/kitchen/tableSetting/about.txt
models/kitchen/tableSetting/meals_any_for_functional_new.learnt.xml.net
models/kitchen/tableSetting/lateMorningConsumption.blogdb
models/kitchen/tableSetting/blnlearn.config.dat
models/kitchen/tableSetting/modelpaper_query1.blogdb
models/kitchen/tableSetting/blnquery.config.dat
models/kitchen/tableSetting/modelpaper_query_A1.blogdb
models/kitchen/tableSetting/blntest_ws1a.blogdb
models/kitchen/tableSetting/modelpaper_query_B1.blogdb
models/kitchen/tableSetting/blntest_ws1b.blogdb
models/kitchen/tableSetting/temp.net
models/kitchen/tableSetting/lorenzExample_errors.txt~
models/kitchen/tableSetting/empty.bln
models/kitchen/tableSetting/example.txt
models/kitchen/tableSetting/gen.py
models/kitchen/tableSetting/gen_log.txt
models/kitchen/tableSetting/whatsMissing_2.blogdb
models/kitchen/tableSetting/lorenz-meals_any_for.alchemy.results
models/kitchen/tableSetting/query_takesPart_given_Utensil.blogdb
models/kitchen/tableSetting/whatsMissing.blogdb
models/kitchen/tableSetting/hs_err_pid9108.log
models/kitchen/tableSetting/lorenzExample.blogdb
models/kitchen/tableSetting/modelpaper_query_A3.blogdb
models/kitchen/tableSetting/lorenzExample.db
models/kitchen/tableSetting/modelpaper_query_A2.blogdb
models/kitchen/tableSetting/lorenzExample2-meals_any_for.alchemy.results
models/kitchen/tableSetting/whatsMissing_4.blogdb
models/kitchen/tableSetting/lorenzExample2-meals_any_for.results

### gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package srldb written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/azfaryusof/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120423-235030/srldb/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< srldb [FAIL] [ 212.86 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package srldb.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< re_ontology [PASS] [ 62.22 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 146 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/azfaryusof/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120423-235030

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32396/rosmake-roboearth-failure/) by [ay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2017/ay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2012-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like a tar archive is broken. Try rosmake --pre-clean to get rid of any downloaded files and, if that does not help, get rid of the broken tar by hand before re-running rosmake.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1